# how can I detect whether the android phone in Silent mode programmatically

Tags: android

How to identify whether the phone is in Silent mode or not?

I am using Android 1.5. I tried by using "android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS". It is not working.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Use the [`getRingerMode()` method in `AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode()).

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave is there any way to toggle Silent as well as vibrating 
mode programatically.

Comment: `setRingerMode()` in `AudioManager` allows you to change the ringer mode.

Comment: Hi Dave I can able to handle the silent mode using 

am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

but handling Vibrating mode using 

AudioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
 
is not working any clue

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly?  I don't think `setVibrateSettings()` does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Following code checks if phone is not in silent mode then plays a beep, written in `kotlin`:

```
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 10, 0)
    val notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val player: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, notification)
    if(manager.ringerMode != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
        player.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen for ringer mode changes means any change in
**Silent** or **Vibrate** or **Normal**
you can set up a broadcast receiver in your activity like below.

```
   private val volumeKeyReceiver: VolumeKeyReceiver by lazy {
        VolumeKeyReceiver()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        registerBroadcastListener()
    }

    private fun registerBroadcastListener() {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction("android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED")
        registerReceiver(volumeKeyReceiver, intentFilter)
    }
```

and unregister when the activity is destroyed like below.

```
 override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(volumeKeyReceiver)
    }
```

and register the receiver in manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".VolumeKeyReceiver"/>
```

here goes the broadcast receiver

```
class VolumeKeyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        //Implement Logic
        val audioManager =
            context?.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as android.media.AudioManager
        when (audioManager.ringerMode) {
            android.media.AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT -> Log.d(
                "VolumeKeyReceiver",
                "Silent mode"
            )
            android.media.AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE -> Log.d(
                "VolumeKeyReceiver",
                "Vibrate mode"
            )
            android.media.AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL -> Log.d(
                "VolumeKeyReceiver",
                "Normal mode"
            )
        }
    }
}
```