# How can I know if the vibrator is working?

Tags: android

Is there any event which is fired when the android phone is vibrating so I can subscribe my event handler to it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: not that [*I'm aware of*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Context.getSystemService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) to get a [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) object. Using that object you can identify whether phone has a vibrator.

```
Vibrator vibrator  = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

to identfiy whether phone has a vibrator, use [hasVibrator()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#hasVibrator%28%29)

```
 vibrator.hasVibrator()
```

You can start and stop vibration using

```
vibrate.vibrate(long milliseconds);
vibrate.cancel();
```

## EDIT: After seeing op's comment..

I don't think you will get notification when phone starts vibrating AFAIK. (Happy if someone clears me wrong).. You can find out whether phone is in vibration mode or silent mode or normal mode (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically)).. But vibration mode doesn't mean phone is vibrating right now..

Comment: I believe he didn't mean if the device has that capability. He wants to subscribe to vibration event.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know whether vibrator is working, or just not working.

Answer (score 0):

getVibrateSetting(int vibrateType) BUT: This method is deprecated. Applications should maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that can be queried via [getRingerMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode%28%29).

Comment: I don't want to know the OS setting or the OS status.

Comment: Your question states: "Could I get the status from the OS service?" and your comment states: "I don't want to know the OS setting or the OS status." Make up my mind what you want friend.