# Android BroadCastReceiver for volume key up and down

Tags: android, android-intent, volume

If a user presses volume key up or down is it possible to detect it in my broadcast receiver? I need the full code.

Here is my Intent filter

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION");
```

and my `onReceive` method is

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
      KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (ke .getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
                System.out.println("I got volume up event");
         }else if (ke .getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("I got volume key down event");
         }
    }
```

It gives me a null KeyEvent... any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The intent does not have an EXTRA_KEY_EVENT extra. It does have an extra android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE which contains the new volume.

```
int volume = (Integer)intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
```

If you store the old value, you can infer whether volume up or down was pressed.

Comment: thanks for your answer but its giving me the same volume value = 1 when phone is on silent or vibrate or on ringer volume is at first step. How I can detect phone is silent or vibrate or no first value?

Comment: you can use the AudioManager to detect whether you are in vibrate, silent or normal mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically

Comment: On volume change at max i started the app but when music player running on device then in that case i do not want to open my app on top of volume change.Any help