# Android service to receive notification when volume changes

Tags: android, service, android-audiomanager

My application runs in the background and gets a notification when the volume on the device changes. The service then has to show a warning message based on the volume levels.

What kind of a service should this be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this, you need to register a broadcastreceiver. Take a look at this question:

[Android BroadCastReceiver for volume key up and down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561142/android-broadcastreceiver-for-volume-key-up-and-down)