# My broadcast receiver class not responding for volume button press?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using broadcast receiver on volume button press for creating a shortcut for call. But broadcast receiver not responding for any volume button press and not getting any exception also.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml class

```
<receiver android:name="com.abc.utilities.CallBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My BroadcastReceiver class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION")){            
        Lod.d("BroadCast", "Volume button pressed."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561142/android-broadcastreceiver-for-volume-key-up-and-down). Check the code in the question

Comment: there is no broadcast event for volume changes in Android

Comment: @XylemRaj is it work in deep sleep mode of device?

Comment: @inner_class7 do you have any example.

Comment: have you registered your broadcast receiver in your activity ?

Comment: no @Gautam actually i want to do in background whether my application is in foreground or in background.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896746/android-is-there-a-broadcast-action-for-volume-changes

Comment: then you need to register your receiver like below Activity.registerReceiver( myBroadcastReceiver, CallBroadcastReceiver);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to code what you want and it's work.

1) I defined my BroacastReceiver in manifest like that :

```
...
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.test.CallBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
...
```

2) I created `CallBroadcastReceiver` :

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int volume = (Integer)intent.getExtras().get("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE");
        Log.i("Tag", "Action : "+ intent.getAction() + " / volume : "+volume);      
    }

}
```

You don't need to check the value of the Action of your intent because your BroadcastReceiver just listened `VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION`. But if you checked the value of your action it's `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION`.

After, I try this app in my Nexus 6, it's possible that the problem comes from the phone.

Comment: i'm not getting any response on volume button press.

Comment: It works for me. I don't understand why, if you have the same code, it doesn't work for you. Try with another phone or emulator or checks that you are not forgotten anything ...