# App capture Key event in background - android

Tags: android, background, keyevent

Is it possible an app capture and handle Key events (Volume_Up, Volume_Down etc) when is in background?

Comment: You have to implement a `Broadcast` receiver for that. Check this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561142/android-broadcastreceiver-for-volume-key-up-and-down

Comment: I think that this solution is not correct. It detects volume_button_press from volume change. In case that volume is Max and user press Volume_up the receiver wont detect the button_press because the old value of volume will be equal to new. Respectively in case of volume_down.