# How to accept Broadcast listener of volume key only when i start my services

Tags: java, android

I start my services by clicking in button and stop my services by stop button.

My Service class is given below

```
public class Services extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
        Log.d("Services","Started...");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("Services","Stoped...");
    }
}
```

My Receiver class is given below

```
public class Reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //check the intent something like:
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP== event.getKeyCode()) {
               Log.d("Volume","Down");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092134/broadcast-receiver-within-a-service)
  ?

Comment: Register the receiver when you are starting your service and unregister the broadcast receiver when you stop your service.

Comment: where do i register and unregister the broadcastreciever?

Comment: i have done intent filter in manifest file as:

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            </intent-filter>

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561142/android-broadcastreceiver-for-volume-key-up-and-down

Comment: Service is `START_NOT_STICKY` So do you have an Activity?

Comment: i am unable to detect volume key pressed.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the internet filters in the manifest and then. In the `Activity` where you are starting the service, along with that register your `BroadcastReciver`and when you stop the service from Activity the activity, after stop UnRegister the `BroadcastRecived`

Register

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
filter.addAction("SOME_OTHER_ACTION");

receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Unregister

```
if (receiver != null) {
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   receiver = null;
}
```

Comment: Read more about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html under the title `Context-registered receivers`

Comment: private void StopClick() {

        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Services.class));

        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    private void Startclick() {

        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Services.class));

        IntentFilter mediaFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mediaFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
        this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, mediaFilter);

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, mediaFilter);

    }