# how can I detect whether the android phone in Silent mode using air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have seen this post [how can I detect whether the android phone in Silent mode programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically)
can any one please tell me whether there is any ane to access the device ringing state whether the device is in silent/vibration mode.
I want to access the device seilent/vibration mode in air mobile app.

Comment: i've seen a sample ane for vibration only so you have to create your own.

Comment: Can you please provide me the ane for vibration thanks

Comment: check [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/vibration.html) out.