# How can I detect phone sound is on or not?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Actually on the net or stackoverflow I cant find the thing I need,maybe I do not searched the real **keyword** on google so I cant find my solution.
I play a sound(**.mp3**) ,it works fine.
code is here:

```
try {
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.bell);
mPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
}
```

My problem is when I take my phone sound is off or vibrate , this code runs and I hear the sound.How can I detect phone sound is not open so I can stop the player,
Thanks in advance

Comment: check to volume level

Comment: thanks I seatch it on google now

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically

Comment: yes thank you @upenpat I dont know the keyword which I should search , thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AudioManager.getStreamVolume http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume%28int%29   to fetch the current volume for the media player stream (See STREAM_MUSIC  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_MUSIC ), and AudioManager.setStreamVolume  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29 to set it.

You can use the following snippet, using AudioManager:

```
AudioManager am = 
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamVolume(
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
    0);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I can tick as correct it after 8 min

Comment: ohk as u wish dear :)