# My app still plays sounds when the phone is on silent

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My Application still plays the sounds when My Phone is on silent.

I think it is because I am using media Player.

```
    MediaPlayer mAlarmPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ConnectingActivity.this, R.raw.echo_affirm1);
    mAlarmPlayer.start();
```

What Alternative am I meant to be using which forces it to comply with the phones current audio state?

In other words what I am looking for, Is the app must not make a sound when the phone is on silent. And if the phone is in normal mode then my tones can be played.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I detect whether the android phone in Silent mode programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically)

Comment: @Nachi - that's certainly worth reading as supporting material, but I don't think it's a duplicate of the question asked here.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Nachi, As I am more looking for a solution that I say play this audio file, and it will look at the phones state, and decide whether to play it aloud or not.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

Call this API in your onCreate():

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

This tells the AudioManager that when your application has focus, the volume keys should adjust music volume.

You have here the [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html)

**Edit:**

About playing the sound even if it is on silent mode, the silent mode checkbox says the following:

> Silence all sounds except media & alarms.

So I suppose that you are trying to play an alarm, and that's why it plays it even if you are in silent mode.

Yo could try using this:

```
if (audioManager.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
    // Play the sound
}
```

Comment: I don't think that I what I am looking for to be honest?  I simply want my app to keep quite when the user has put the one on silent.

Comment: Look at the first answer here - gives more info about different modes: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically#_=_">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048427/how-can-i-detect-whether-the-android-phone-in-silent-mode-programatically#_=_</a>